# How to annotate the type of field in dataclass to be different from the type of its __init__?

Tags: python, mypy, python-dataclasses

I created a dataclass `Foo`, which accepts any type that can be converted to `int`:

```py
import dataclasses


@dataclasses.dataclass
class Foo:
    a: int

    def __post_init__(self):
        # Here `self.a` is converted to int, so this class accepts any type that can be converted to int
        self.a = int(self.a)


# mypy error: Argument 1 to "Foo" has incompatible type "str"; expected "int",
foo = Foo("1")
print(foo)
print(foo.a + 2)
```

Output:

```
Foo(a=1)
3
```

However, mypy reports the below error:

```
error: Argument 1 to "Foo" has incompatible type "str"; expected "int"
```

If I fix the type of `Foo.a` to `Union[str, int]`, mypy reports another error:

```
error: Unsupported operand types for + ("str" and "int")
```

How to write a dataclass whose type of the field and the init argument are different?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to decouple the `a` field from the `a` argument that `__init__` takes. This would essentially require both an

```
a: InitVar[Union[SupportsInt, str]]
```

and an

```
a: int = field(init=False)
```

one to describe the `__init__` argument, and one to describe the field. You can't do that, though. An InitVar and a field can't have the same name.

Your best option is to not use a dataclass, but if you're absolutely determined to do things that way, you'll have to write your own `__init__`:

```
@dataclasses.dataclass
class Foo:
    a: int
    
    def __init__(self, a: typing.Union[typing.SupportsInt, str]):
        self.a = int(a)
```

Comment: thanks! Is there anything I should be aware of to overwrite `dataclass.__init__`?

Comment: I'm afraid to break something special which is usually generated `dataclass` by replacing `__init__` by my own.

Comment: @Yohei: Well, `__post_init__` won't run (unless you call it yourself), and you'll have to manually set all the fields that would normally be handled for you, as well as handling defaults and default factories.

Comment: NOTE: if you're using `@dataclass(frozen=True)`, you'll have to use `object.__setattr__(self, 'a', int(a))` instead of simple assignment in your `__init__`.